# Groupby gender and count missing values in height column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have table like this below, and i need to find the value counts of the Gender column only for rows where Height is missing.

```
Age  Gender  Height  Weight NonAlcoholicDrink AlcoholicDrink
0  19.0    Male     NaN     NaN            Coffee            NaN
1   NaN  Female   64.50  128.70             Water         Liquor
2  21.0    Male   71.47  182.95            Coffee           Beer
3  32.0  Female   57.30  103.40         Green Tea           Wine
4  32.0  Female   53.80  138.40         Black Tea         Liquor
5  20.0    Male   73.38  204.59             Pepsi            NaN
6  20.0    Male   70.46  225.25            Coffee            NaN
7  32.0  Female   54.10  157.80         Black Tea         Liquor
8  49.0  Female   64.80  152.60          Gatorade           Beer
9  45.0    Male     NaN  196.55            Coffee         Liquor
```

What should i do?

Comment: Please share witth us what you have already tried to calculate this?

Comment: print('Count of missing Height by Gender')
print(DrinkPreferences.Height.isnull().groupby([DrinkPreferences['Gender']]).sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='Height'))

Comment: but it says  i get incorrect output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can get the answer is to create a new dataframe where Height values are `np.nan` (which you have 2 in your above sample), by doing:

```
missing_height = df[df['Height'].isnull()]
```

Then you can use the new dataframe, and do a `value_counts()`, to get what you need:

```
missing_height['Gender'].value_counts(ascending=False)
```

which will get you what you need.